# How to use relations between models in a Firebase database with Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have a very simple Firebase database which looks like this:
[image]

The first model is `ProfessorModel` and looks like this:

```
public class ProfessorModel {
private String professorId;
private String professorName;

public ProfessorModel() {}

public ProfessorModel(String professorId, String professorName, Courses courses) {
    this.professorId = professorId;
    this.professorName = professorName;
    this.courses = courses;
}

public void setProfessorId(String professorId) {this.professorId = professorId;}
public String getProfessorId() {return professorId;}

public void setProfessorName(String professorName) {this.professorName = professorName;}
public String getProfessorName() {return professorName;}

public void setCourses(Courses courses) {this.courses = courses;}
public Courses getCourses() {return courses;}

public static class Courses {
    private String courseName;

    public Courses() {}

    public Courses(String courseName) {this.courseName = courseName;}

    public void setCourseName(String courseName) {this.courseName = courseName;}
    public String getCourseName() {return courseName;}
}
```

And the second one is `CourseModel` and looks like this:

```
public class CourseModel {
private String courseName;

public CourseModel() {}

public CourseModel(String courseName) {
this.courseName = courseName;
}

public void setCourseName(String courseName) {this.courseName = courseName;}
public String getCourseName() {return courseName;}
```

This is how i add a `course`:

```
CourseModel cm = new CourseModel(courseName);
DatabaseReference courseRef = ref.push();
String key = courseRef.getKey();
courseRef.setValue(cm);

professorsRef.child(professorId).child("courses").child(key).setValue(courseName);
```

When i try to display the `Course1` and `Course2` from `ProfessorModel` using this code:

```
 DatabaseReference coursesRef = professorsRef.child(professorId).child("courses");
    FirebaseListAdapter adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ProfessorModel>(this, ProfessorModel.class, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, coursesRef) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(final View v, ProfessorModel professorModel, int position) {
            String courseName = professorModel.getCourses().getCourseName();
            ((TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(courseName);
        }
    };
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I get this error: `Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.firebasedatabase.Models.ProfessorModel`. How can i get the `course names` and display them correctly using `professorModel.getCourses().getCourseName()`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your adapter, you clearly use `ProfessorModel.class`, so you should pass reference that point to `professor` value, like `professorsRef.child(professorId)` (without adding `child("courses")`)

Comment: Thanks koceeng for your answer. I just removed `child("courses")` and now i get this error: `java.lang.NullPointerException` on this line: `String courseName = professorModel.getCourses().getCourseName();` Do you have any idea why?

Comment: See in your `Professor`, you have one single `Course` object, but in your database structure, it is kind of array of courses. If you don't plan to change the structure, then rather than using custom object (`Course`), why just use simple `HashMap<String, String> courses`?

Comment: I can change my database structure, there will not be a problem but i don't know how. All i want to do, is to use only `setters` and `getters`. Like in my code: `professorModel.getCourses().getCourseName();` from the nested class, which is null now.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because your variables are private in `ProfessorModel`. Return value might couldn't access to your model. Try out with `public` variables.

Comment: Thanks but no effect! Any other idea?

Comment: And also make public `courseName` in `CourseModel`.  After removing `.child("courses")` as koceeng says. @AlexM.

Comment: I did this, but also no effect! :|